# Disable column editing in devexpress MVC Grid View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, devexpress

How to disable column editing when using devexpress MVC Grid View mode is inline editing

Comment: Have you seen this support question: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q406756?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a readonly attribute to your column in the Partial View:

```
settings.Columns.Add(column =>
{
    column.FieldName = "MyField";
    column.ReadOnly = true;
});
```